# Auth using passport.js confusion with syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

There are a few things in passport.js that I don't understand.

1.

```js
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

What does `null` represent in the `done()` function. It seems to be the first parameter always and I am confused about what is actually does?

2.

```js
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, cb) {
  cb(null, obj);
});
```

What does serialize and deserialize do? Does serialize get called after a login when session is stored in the browser? And deserialize is when a page is accessed so the session is deserialized on the server to validate that user?

Lastly what is the `null` parameter again in `cb(null, user);`

Comment: There's a convention in nodejs to pass any errors along in the first argument of callbacks. You'll see this in pretty much every node library, including the built in modules like `fs`. So passing `null` is like saying that no errors occurred inside the function before giving the result to the callback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. what does null represent in the done() function. It seems to be the first parameter always and I am confused about what is actually does?
>
>    - what is the null parameter again in cb(null, user);

By convention, NodeJS uses **error-first callbacks** which means the first argument to callback functions is always the error object. If you don't have any errors, you pass in `null`. In other words, if the error argument is `null`, then the operation was successful and if the error argument is not `null`, then an error has occurred. This holds true for all the examples you asked about. If you look at the code you can see that you are already leveraging this:

```
User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) { 
    // Error happened and passed as first argument
    return done(err); 
  } 

  // ...

  // no error so we pass in null
  return done(null, user);
```

Furthermore, Passport has the convention for its authentication process where, as their docs say:

> If the credentials are valid, the verify callback invokes `done` to supply Passport with the user that authenticated. If the credentials are not valid (for example, if the password is incorrect), `done` should be invoked with false instead of a user to indicate an authentication failure.

That's what you are doing here:

```
User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {

  // ...

  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
  }
  if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
  }

  // ...
```

---

> 2. What does serialize and deserialize do? Does serialize get called after a login when session is stored in the browser? and deserialize is when a page is accessed so the session is deserialized on the server to validate that user?

Well, Passport's documentation says:

> If authentication succeeds, a session will be established and maintained via a cookie set in the user's browser. Each subsequent request will not contain credentials, but rather the unique cookie that identifies the session. In order to support login sessions, Passport will serialize and deserialize user instances to and from the session.

This means that, after the user logs in, `serializeUser` is called and the user data you pass to the callback `cb`:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user); // <-- this user object
});
```

is saved in the session store (usually browser cookies) and made available at `req.session.passport.user` in your code.

When the user reconnects to your page (either by refreshing or leaving and coming back), this same data is passed as the first parameter to `deserializeUser` to be used retrieve the user object.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, cb) {
  cb(null, obj); // <-- obj is the same `user` object you used in serializeUser
});
```

What you are doing here is passing the actual `user` object to the callback in `serializeUser` and then passing that same object back through the callback in `deserializeUser`. This means you are storing the entire user object in your cookies which is ok for playing around but not generally a good idea since cookie storage is limited plus user information is usually sensitive.

The typical way to do this is to pass the user id, not the whole user object, to `cb` in `serializeUser` to keep the amount of data stored within the session small. When further requests happen, this id is passed to `deserializeUser` and used to find the actual user object, usually from the database, which will be restored to `req.user`.

Here's an example:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```